# Fetching Alchemist, Excavation I

Tags: mathematics, optimization, graph-theory, video-games

[image]

This is a puzzle in the [Fetching Alchemist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bizleycraft.fetchingalchemist) series. It has been generated especially for Puzzling Stack Exchange.

Please note that, in my opinion, imperfect solutions should be up-voted so long as they work and are lower than previous guesses. This makes them useful, since they inform other players of whether they have a possible solution or not.

---

### How to Play

You are looking for the shortest possible path that allows you to complete all the quests. You choose where you start. The red numbers indicate the distance of each road. Present your answer in the form "99: ABCDE...", where the numbers are the total path distance and the letters are the place you started at followed by the places you visit on the path.

You complete a quest by either starting there or travelling there with the required items in your inventory, which are consumed upon completing the quest (if the quest has required items, indicated by the presence of items left of an arrow under the quest).

The items drawn around places are the reward items for the quests that can be completed there.

You can complete a quest more than once but only once per place.

You cannot avoid completing a quest that you are able to complete where you are. This includes when you have no need for the quest reward.

You can complete more than one quest in the same place. When completing more than one quest in the same place, quests are completed automatically from top to bottom. Consequently, completing a higher quest may prevent completing a lower quest.

If you would obtain an item from completing a quest, you can use it to complete a quest in the same place without travelling again.

Comment: Remember downvotes aren't meant to be used like dislikes on this site. If you down-vote, you should have an objection, and unless someone else has already commented with that objection, you should add a comment yourself. I say this because two FA puzzles got down-votes today with no comment. Conversely, remember to up-vote if you are enjoying these and want me to keep posting these daily.

Comment: No one is ever obligated to explain downvotes. No one is even obligated to have an objection that they can put into words at the moment. See [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416). Of course serial voting is bad, and [explaining downvotes is encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135) if someone feels up to it.

Comment: @bobble The question you have linked relates to how the site should be designed. I agree that the site shouldn't force people to leave comments on uncommented mistakes but I stand by the claim that they "should", at least when what is wrong with the question isn't objectively obvious to someone (like me) who has been using the site for a while. The comment I made here is here as encouragement for down-votes to be used in as helpful a way as possible.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but usually there is a level of "puzzle-type fatigue" on this site, where posting the same type of puzzles on overly many posts is frowned upon.

Comment: @justhalf Sure, I'll post these less then.

Comment: You can post it again after some time, I think. But yea, I guess slowing down on the same type of puzzle is good for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start off with

> <s>73: ABFDKMK</s> **66: ABFJDK**

Why?

> We can only pick up Shae from A or E. If we don't visit A, then the closest place we can get Shae's hammer is G and the closest fossil is I - that's way too much distance for a single objective.
>  Starting at A means we only have to cross the map one way.
>  From there, its only a matter of getting two Energy Potions and another Lantern and dropping them off, then backtracking to the Fossil.